# Dropping last record with autoincrementing primary key

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose you have a database with an auto-incrementing primary key and 25 records (PK goes from 1 to 25). Delete the record whose PK=25; PK values will now go from 1-24. Finally add a new record. Its PK value will be 25.

This would be quite problematic if other tables used the value 25 as a foreign key. They would would be linked to an erroneous record.

How is this issue customarily addressed?

Comment: The FK constraint (when enforced) forbids a record to be deleted if another table has a FK pointing to this record. What will happen if this situation occurs (to cascade or to not cascade) is secondary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all databases, once allocated, the auto increment value will not be reused even if the original row is deleted.

There is an exception in SQLite if you rely on the built-in ROWID value rather than declaring a column to be AUTOINCREMENT.  In the second case, things work as you expect (values are never recycled).  In the first case, however, in the situation you describe (deletion of highest-numbered row), the value *will* be recycled.

But consider that in the case which you describe where the ROWID is used as a primary key and *all other references are protected with an enforced foreign key relationship* then, in order to delete the record with value 25, all references to it must first be removed from the database.

The problem only occurs when you have *non-enforced* references to the primary key value.

Nonetheless, I think it's a best practice to explicitly declare the primary key to be AUTOINCREMENT.  A counter-argument can be read here: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html.

Comment: Looking at the docs (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) it's clear I am inadvertently using ROWID values, because of how I declared my tables.

Comment: Yes, if you can rebuild the DB with that column declared AUTOINCREMENT you should see the other behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use uniquidentifiers? I suggest if you are not constrained.